# Create Exchange account from Java

Tags: java, exchange-server

I know there are multiple Java API to interface with MS Exchange, but it seems to me that no one that offers methods for mailbox creation. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do it using [HtmlUnit](http://www.google.com.sa/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=HtmlUnit&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/&ei=myYUT4bhE-j74QTGu7GKBA&usg=AFQjCNHPMijLD6lsJhr_pTp_Ysz3XN3dHA&sig2=STm5ROqxIv4ySJswzrNPTw) API.

> HtmlUnit is a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs". It models HTML
>   documents and provides an API that allows you to invoke pages, fill
>   out forms, click links, etc... just like you do in your "normal"
>   browser.
>
> It has fairly good JavaScript support (which is constantly improving)
>   and is able to work even with quite complex AJAX libraries, simulating
>   either Firefox or Internet Explorer depending on the configuration you
>   want to use.
>
> It is typically used for testing purposes or to retrieve information
>   from web sites.

Comment: HtmlUnit JavaScript support is very limited. I've failed once to deal with AJAX page, but maybe you will have more luck.